# Changing Timer Interval in Backgroundworker DoWork Disables the Timer [C#]

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, backgroundworker, intervals

I have the problem with changing the timer Interval in backgroundworker's DoWork event. While changing the Interval by clicking the Button, Timer stops and doesn't start again.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Simple code:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timerTest.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTest_Tick);
        timerTest.Interval = 1000;
        timerTest.Start();
    }

    private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        push = true;
    }

    private void timerTest_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ticks++;
        labelTest.Text = ticks.ToString();
        if(running == false)
        {
            running = true;
            backgroundWorkerTest.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    public void activate()
    {
        timerTest.Stop();
        timerTest.Interval = 4000;
        timerTest.Start();
    }

    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        while(running)
        {
           if(push == true)
           {
               activate();  
           }
        }
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        running = false;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The Timer class is thread-safe but not in a way that anybody ever likes.  It works fine as long as you don't call Stop().  The code is too fake to give proper advice.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It took me a while, but I found out what was wrong. I'll post you a working code, just in case someone will have the same problem.

public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public int ticks = 0;
        public bool running = false;
        public bool push = false;

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timerTest.Tick += new EventHandler(timerTest_Tick);
        timerTest.Interval = 1000;
        timerTest.Start();
    }

    private void buttonTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        push = true;
    }

    private void timerTest_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ticks++;
        labelTest.Text = ticks.ToString();
        if(running == false)
        {
            running = true;
            backgroundWorkerTest.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }

    public void activate()
    {
        ZmienIntervalNaAwaryjny = true;
    }
    public bool ZmienIntervalNaAwaryjny = false;
    private void DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {

           if(push == true)
           {
               activate();
           }
    }

    private void Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(ZmienIntervalNaAwaryjny == true)
        {
            timerTest.Stop();
            timerTest.Interval = 12000;
            timerTest.Start();
        }
        ZmienIntervalNaAwaryjny = false;
        running = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never set `push` to false.

Therefore, the following code:

```
    while(running)
    {
       if(push == true)
       {
           activate();  
       }
    }
```

will continuously call `activate()` in a tight loop. `activate()` stops the timer and then restarts it, and the time between calls to it will be far less than the timer interval. Therefore, the timer will never be left long enough to fire.

In any case, why don't you call `activate()` directly from `buttonTest_Click()`?

Answer (score 0):

I can see this was asked a long time ago, but for the reference:

When it comes to timers or threadings in general (remember timer is system.threading) in combination with background workers (tasks) Never ever try to change a thread proerties randomly without knowing what the worker is doing.

It is always a good practice when assigning the DoWork handler to prepare the background worker Progress and Complete handlers as well.
At each cycle, report the progress or the completion, this would give you the chance to do your checks and modify another thread properties if needed.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
 while (!worker.CancellationPending)
{
  // do task 1 as per the timer1 interval
  // do task 2 as per such and such .....
  // if I call ChangeInterval here I'll be fiddling with another thread when 
  //  this is still in progress 
  // that a full loop, Progress will be reported now

  }
 }
   private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender,ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
     {
       // Now as the Do work is not in progress
       // do something 
       // check if the user wanted to change the interval ?
       // if yes then
       ChangeInterval(6000);
       // here the progress reporting is done so it will go back to DoWork with the 
       // NewInterval Value in place and the timer enabled
     }

     private void ChangeInterval(int NewInterval)
     {
       timer1.Enabled =false;
       timer1.Interval = NewInterval;
       timer1.Enabled = true;
     }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try invoke your `activate` method with the UI Thread's Dispatcher. (*Assuming Win Forms?*)

```
this.Invoke(new Action(activate));
```

Reason is that your `timer` is a UI control and you're updating the `Interval` on a separate thread. This will throw a **Cross-Thread exception**.

**Why don't you see the exception?** When the `DoWork` method in your `BackgroundWorker` throws an exception, it will be propogated to the `Completed` method. So you should always look at `e.Error` to see if an exception occurred.

```
private void Completed(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Error != null)
    {
        // Oh no something went wrong...
    }

    running = false;
}
```